# Changing Razer Diamondback 3g additional buttons in xorg.conf

Tags: drivers, xorg, mouse

So I am trying to change how my mouse additional buttons behave when clicked. Currently they do nothing on GNU/Linux. But I made these changes to my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier "Configured Mouse"
   Driver "mouse"
   Option "Name" "Razer Diamondback Optical Mouse"
   Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
   Option "CorePointer"
   Option "Resolution" "1600"
   Option "Buttons" "9"
   Option "Protocol" "ExplorerPS/2"
   Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
   Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 6 7 8 9"
   Option "one page back" "4"
   Option "one page forward" "5"
EndSection
```

Now this enables me to use the 2 first buttons to navigate back and forward with the mouse, but I would like to make it so that the 2 left buttons press numpad 4 ,5 and right ones 6, 7.   But my knowledge is not that good to make such changes. Can anyone lend a hand?